# How to write a button that can exit the dialog of jquery ui?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

In jquery UI modal dialog, I want to have a button which can trigger some function, and at the same time quit the dialog. How can do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
    buttons: { 
        "Close": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
            // some function call
        } 
    } 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vGn7k/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
    buttons: { 
        "Close": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
            // some function call
        } 
    } 
});
```

This is a bad idea; better use native close button on top right corner of dialog window.

```
$('.dialog').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mydialog').dialog({
        close: function(e) {
            alert('You just closed me');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VGS5L/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="dialog">Open dialog</a>

<div id="mydialog">
    <p>My dialog</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mydialog {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.dialog').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mydialog').dialog({
        close: function(e) {
            alert('You just closed me');
        }
    });
});
```

In this part of the code

```
close: function(e) {
    alert('You just closed me');
}
```

you can put in your function or a callback. By default, the close link is made for you.